# MQ Message integer property not updataing

Tags: jms, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

I have a MQ Message. In that, I add an Integer property called "Count" with the value 10. Then I reassign the value to 5 for the same property.But it is not getting updated.

```
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
message.writeString("Test Message");
message.setIntProperty("Count", 10);
System.out.println("Count is" + message.getIntProperty("Count")); -->Prints 10
message.setIntProperty("Count",5);
System.out.println("Count is" + message.getIntProperty("Count")); --> Prints 10..But I am expecting 5..
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the message to a queue? If you actually put the message to a queue and get the same message back, you will see that updated value of the property is set in the message i.e. value of "Count" property will be 5, instead of 10.